# gathering information form multiple data frames based on a reference data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to construct sentences, the words come from the first 3 data frames

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
    df1['w']=['i', 'am', 'python', 'is', 'set', 'sail']
    df1['n'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    df2 =pd.DataFrame()
    df2['w']=['i', 'wish', 'in', 'love', 'has' ]
    df2['n'] =[1,2,3,4,5]
    df3 = pd.DataFrame()
    df3['w']=['the', 'ship', 'with', 'you', 'my', 'friend']
    df3['n']=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

the parts are defined here, and locations for words of each sentence and boundary

```
string= pd.DataFrame()
string['location'] = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df2', 'df1', 'df3', 'df3', 'df2', 'df1']
string['start'] = [1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 5]
string['stop'] = [2 , 4, 4, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 6]
string['sentence] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
string['part'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

the desired output is

```
i am in love with you 
i wish pyhton is my fried
**boundry**
the ship has set sail
**boundry**
```

the code I have tried is, I have found this o far it seems to do most of what I want but I cut figure out how to Mae it work with multiple tables, and get the order I am after.

```
x = df1.set_index('n')['w']
sent = [
    ' '.join(x.loc[i:j]) for i, j in zip(string['start'], string['stop'])
]

sent
```

the output I get is

```
['i am',
 'python is',
 'python is',
 'i',
 'python is',
 'set sail',
 'i am',
 'set',
 'set sail']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string['res'] = string.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(globals()[x['location']].iloc[(x['start']-1):(x['stop'])]['w']),axis=1)
print string['res'].values.tolist()
```

output:

```
['i am', 'in love', 'with you', 'i wish', 'python is', 'my friend', 'the ship', 'has', 'set sail']
```

For further Result (Adding Boundary):

```
string['res'] = string.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(globals()[x['location']].iloc[(x['start']-1):(x['stop'])]['w']),axis=1)
string.loc[~string['part'].duplicated(keep='last'),'flag']='boundry'

l=list(string['res'].values)
b = list(np.where(string['flag'].values == 'boundry')[0])
[l.insert(ind+i,'boundary') for i,ind in enumerate(b,1)]
print l
```

Output:

```
['i am', 'in love', 'with you', 'i wish', 'python is', 'my friend', 'boundary', 'the ship', 'has', 'set sail', 'boundary']
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamed thank you for giving me a lead, however supposed I have 200 different locations, it would be too labor intensive to type dic={'df1':df1,'df2':df2,'df3':df3 ....... 'df200':df200}

Comment: @Ryan - sorry for the delayed reply. updated to the solution

Comment: HI @Mohamed, That reads it in but I still have no idea how to get the desired format based on the part field

Comment: @Ryan - I didn't understand the query. what is part field?

Comment: Can you get the output what I have posted in my answer ?

Comment: @ Mohamed the part field should be used to give the desired output

Comment: Hi Mohamed, sorry I believe I should edit my initial codes

Comment: @ Mohamed it is working but I am still trying to get the desired output.

Comment: @Ryan - what is your desired output. I got the same output what you had described in last comment